# I have Input in format of 9:ak-IT-ABC;2:others- -su1; ..... ; in one cell, How to separate these values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have Input in format of:

```
9:ak-IT-ABC;2:others- -su1; ..... ;
```

in one cell, how to separate these values in excel & write in another sheet?

Input:

```
9:ak-IT-ABC;2:others- -su1; ..... ;
```

Output want:

```
 A    B     C    D
 9    ak    IT   ABC
 2    others     su1
```

Comment: Open in Notepad++, Use CTRL+H to go to "replace" and replace every `;` with `\t`

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Text-to-Columns on the cell, delimited by semicolon(;).  That will separate the entries horizontally.  Copy all entries and paste special/transpose them in a blank worksheet.  That will make them all vertical.  Do two more delimited Text-to-Columns separations on the vertical entries.  The first would be by colon (:), and the second would be by hyphen (-).  That should separate them all out the way you are asking.

Does it have to be done by VBA?